# Ansible: How to use register in loop

Tags: loops, ansible

## ansible  version 1.9.1

## cat files.yml

```
tasks:
  - name: stat files
    stat: path=~/{{ item }}
    register: {{ item }}.stat
    with_items:
      - foo.zip
      - bar.zip

  - name: copy files
    copy: src=~/{{ item }} dest=/tmp/{{ item }}
    register: {{ item }}.result
    when: {{ item }}.stat.stat.exists == False
    with_items:
      - foo.zip
      - bar.zip

- name: unzip files
  shell: cd /tmp/ && unzip -o {{ item }}
  when: {{ item }}.result|changed == True
  with_items:
    - foo.zip
    - bar.zip
```

ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way would be to use `synchronize` module. 
From ansible documentation ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html#synopsis )

> This is a wrapper around rsync. Of course you could just use the command action to call rsync yourself, but you also have to add a fair number of boilerplate options and host facts. You still may need to call rsync directly via command or shell depending on your use case. The synchronize action is meant to do common things with rsync easily. It does not provide access to the full power of rsync, but does make most invocations easier to follow.

Here is an example:

```
- name: Sync files
  synchronize: src=some/relative/path dest=/some/absolute/path
```